# Confused about ios image size on different iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a general question about how images are displayed on iphone
For example iphone 5, 5s support 320x568 points or 640x1136 pixles.
If I want to create 4 images all same size to take the whole screen when rendered in 5s portrait mode, can I say each image should be 160x284 pixels? 
Now what if the same app is now rendered in 4s or 6? How the images are displayed? Those 4 160x284 images are still taking the whole screen?

Thanks

Comment: How do you want that 160x284 pixels image will fit iPhone 5s screen? Do you mean stretching?

Answer (score 1):

Yes the images can scale to take up the whole screen but will appear blurry. If you want the images to be crisp you will need to create 3 different versions for the 3 different pixel densities (iPhone 2-3, iPhone 4-5, iPhone 6). The general convention is to name your assets like this:

- image.png
- image@2x.png
- image@3x.png

[Here's](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions) a handy guide I use that explains how things are rendered on the different models.

Comment: So in this case I need to create total of 12 images (4-160x240 for iphone 2,3 which 2 will be on top and 2 on the bottom to take the whole screen, 4-320x480 for iphone 4 and 5, and finally  4-375x667 for iphone 6)
Now what if the phone rotated to landscape mode. Again the images will be scaled and will not appear right? How do you handle that?

Comment: For images that take up the full screen. I normally make them for the iPhone6+ at 414x736 points (meaning the 1x version is 414x736 pixels) and use aspect fill on the image views that display them. It just depends on how much control you need.

Comment: iPhone >=4, 5, 6 and 6plus all have a different amount of points. Also only the 6+ will render @ 3x, the others between 4-6 will do @ 2x. If these are fullscreen images you'll need 4-160x240 @ 1x, 4-375x667 @ 2x , 4-414x736 @ 3x. For the images @ 2x design them taking into account that they will be partially cut off by iPhone 5(320x568) and iPhone 4(320x480).

Comment: thanks, those make sense. Now what about when the phone is in landscape mode? I am assuming the images will get stretched. Do I need another set of images for landscape mode?

Comment: Yeah they'll get stretched so you'll need another set if you want to preserve the same quality as portrait mode.